# RabbitMQ: connect ECONNREFUSED error. Cant connect to the 5672 port

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to learn RabbitMQ. I am using the following code that I got from tutorials:

**publisher.js:**

```
const amqp = require("amqplib/callback_api");

amqp.connect(`amqp://localhost`, (err, connection) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  connection.createChannel((err, channel) => {
    const queueName = 'queue';
    const message = 'This is the message to send'
    channel.assertQueue(queueName, {
        durable:false,
    });
    channel.sendToQueue(queueName, Buffer.from(message));
    console.log('Message: ' + message);
    setTimeout(()=>{
        connection.close();
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

When I run publisher.js using node in the CLI, I get this error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5672
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 5672
}
```

I was expecting:

- Console log with the message
- Message should also be added to the queue

Is it a TCP connection or firewall issue? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: is RabbitMQ running when you start your application?

Comment: I tried: "brew services start rabbitmq" and "rabbitmq-server". And then running the file and still get the same error.

Comment: You installed it and verified it was installed correctly? See this article: https://dyclassroom.com/howto-mac/how-to-install-rabbitmq-on-mac-using-homebrew

Answer (score 1):

Instead of localhost, use 127.0.0.1
That should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you this works, but can you explain why? I'm on a m1 mac. Do mac do something that prevents using localhost?